# Laravel mix - class from variable isnt builded

Tags: laravel, laravel-mix

my class from variable is not working, im sure its mix problem.

```
<div class="rounded bg-gradient-to-r {{$replay->playerOneTeam()}}">
    Team: {{ $replay->playerOneTeam()}}
</div>
```

It seems like purgeCSS or something is removing class `"from-red-400"`. When I set it manually and do `npm run dev` it works, but when it's used from variable, it's not loading. The class is in code when I inspect but the code runs like it doesn't exist.

Comment: Is this Tailwind CSS? If so and you're compiling using JIT mode, I suppose that the compiler just doesn't see the class since it can't interpret the value of your PHP variables (because these will be known at runtime). [More about this here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode). There is a section with do's and don'ts regarding dynamic values.

Comment: Yes i am using tailwind css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `tailwind.config.js` file and look for something like this:

```
module.exports = {
    mode: 'jit',
    purge: [
        './vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pagination/resources/views/*.blade.php',
        './vendor/laravel/jetstream/**/*.blade.php',
        './storage/framework/views/*.php',
        './resources/views/**/*.blade.php',
        './resources/js/**/*.vue',
    ],
    // ...
}
```

In this example, JIT mode is enabled and `purge` is where you can specify files where to look for used Tailwind CSS classes. From here, you have three options:

1. [**Not recommended**] Disable JIT mode.
2. Follow the guidelines [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode) to make sure the compiler sees your class name in those files you specified, i.e. [to write purgeable HTML code in those files](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/optimizing-for-production#writing-purgeable-html).
3. Divide `purge` into `content` and `safelist` so the compiler doesn't accidentally remove your classes specified there (which will be classes that **do not appear explicitly** in [purgeable HTML code](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/optimizing-for-production#writing-purgeable-html)).

Using the example above, the third option would look something like this:

```
module.exports = {
    mode: 'jit',
    purge: {
        content: [
            './vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pagination/resources/views/*.blade.php',
            './vendor/laravel/jetstream/**/*.blade.php',
            './storage/framework/views/*.php',
            './resources/views/**/*.blade.php',
            './resources/js/**/*.vue',
        ],
        safelist: [
            'from-red-400', // this is the class you wanted

            // ... some other classes you may need

            'bg-blue-500', // example class
            'text-center', // example class
            'hover:opacity-100', // example class
        ]
    },
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in 2023, if someone has the same problem, this was the solution that I found working:

Add this in tailwind.config.js

```
safelist: [
        'bg-blue-100',
        {
            pattern: /bg-(gray|red|orange|amber|yellow|green|lime|blue|sky|teal|indigo|violet|purple|pink)-(50|100|200|300|400)/,
        },
        {
            pattern: /text-(gray|red|orange|amber|yellow|green|lime|blue|sky|teal|indigo|violet|purple|pink)-(500|600|700|800)/,
        },
    ],
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).